# Searching text about school girl growing wings and trying to hide them at first

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

I am looking for a book for young adults. I have read it in the past and that must be some years by now. I guess I read it 2010 to 2015.

---

The plot is about a girl that first gets some "bumps" on her back then these rise to real wings. She tries to hide them as she continues to claim to be a normal girl going to school etc. She is embarrassed by the situation and tries to hide it. She binds the wings to her back with bandages/cloth/... so no one will notify the "misshapen" wings.

No one explains anything to her. At some point she was invited to a costume party (of some sort) by a friend of hers and just went there "masked" as angel. She entertains herself again and uses a TV remote (?) to "control" the wings.
Some older angel finds her here there and harshly takes her away as she was never meant to handle the situation on her own. In fact, she should have never shown herself to the public with her wings.

I think she was in danger by the big antagonists (daemons, whatever) and in fact the older angel saved her from being kidnapped (?), especially as she is completely untrained and would thus be vulnerable.

---

The rest of the story is a blurry mess in my brain, so I cannot tell you more about it.

I think I read it on my Kindle library but I am not sure and I am not able to find anything matching. The story also seems not too clear in my brain to allow me to Google it efficiently.

I am not sure about the type of the book. I did not hold it physically in my hands. So, I am unsure about the number of pages let alone if it was a novella, a novel or even (the start of) a series.

I bought quite a lot of low-budget titles back then on Amazon. It was a Kindle book for sure. There are a lot of books in my library that I believe were published as ebook only. This could hold true for the book in question as well.

Also, I am unsure about the language. I could have read it in English or in German. Both would be okay; I would just need an initial "hook".

I even tried to use ChatGPT to no success. I was forwarded to a (ominous) book "The Gift" from Marcus Sedgwick. I however nowhere found anything that indicated that book was ever published (neither amazon not google did even indicate any useful hit).

Comment: In roughly which year did you read this?

Comment: As far as I can reproduce, my kindle library is from the ages 2010 till 2018. Most probably the first 5 years.

Comment: @Christian Wolf  According to Christian theology angels are ageless beings of spirit, who have the power to make bodies for themselves which are more like unliving robots controlled by their will than living bodies.  Thus the author may have deliberately misused the for angel for biological beings who are born and grow for the purposes of their story.

Comment: ^_^ To be fair, there has been a lot of attempt to reason out angels in the religious literature. The common bit about how many angels can dance on the head of a pin is a pithy take on their material or immaterial nature.

Comment: Parts of this are reminiscent of Bonnie Silver from *Dragons in Our Midst* / *Oracles of Fire* (published 2004-2009), but the costume party bit doesn't match at all, so I don't think that's it.

Comment: @DLosc I thought of that too, but Bonnie enters the story with her wings fully formed, and OP would almost certainly remember that the main character of that story could breathe fire.

Answer (score 13):

## *Wings*, by Aprilynne Pike

I've read this book and I've met the author. It's totally a young adult paranormal romance, and there are several points that match your story.

1. It came out in 2009, so your timeline of 2010-2015 fits
2. Her wings start as a bump/pimple on her back, and it ends up growing into a sort of flower, and ends up being her wings.
3. She has a protector watching over her. (She is living with the humans so she can inherit land that has a gate to the rest of her kind)
4. There were big antagonists that they called "Trolls" who are intelligent and are trying to buy the land so she can't inherit it, and so that they'll control the gate instead.
5. She binds the petals/wings to her back with bandages to hide them while she's at school.
6. She goes to a school costume dance with her blossom as a part of her costume.

The only things that don't match are:

1. I don't remember her using a remote to control the wings (or pretending to do so).
2. She dresses as a Faerie, not an angel.

I'm not sure how firm your memory is on those two points?

Comment: I would not call myself fool-prove as I have just seen with a different topic. I am pretty sure but i have to check this one out. It sounds promising at least.

Answer (score 7):

I haven't read it, but "Growing Wings" by Laurel Winter [sounds at least somewhat similar](https://www.kirkusreviews.com/book-reviews/laurel-winter/growing-wings/):

> While 11 is a time in a girl’s life when her body is undergoing changes, Linnet’s physical changes are highly unusual—she is growing wings. To her amazement, this bizarre fact doesn’t surprise her mother Sarah, who it turns out also had wings at Linnet’s age. But Linnet’s grandmother had cut off Sarah’s wings, not being able to imagine her navigating her way though life with them. After the school term ends, Linnet insists on going to look for, as she puts it, “anyone else like me.” After several days of travel and after being abandoned by her mother, Linnet ends up at her grandmother’s, who takes Linnet to an isolated house way up in the mountains, a secret place where other winged people live. Safe in the community of others like herself, Linnet and one of the others, Andy, try to teach themselves to fly but for various aeronautical reasons, they are both unable to. Linnet and Andy finally realize that they are unwilling to hide for the rest of their lives, even if it means being called freaks by intolerant people. The two kids decide to take their chances in the outside world with non-winged people.

(The granddaddy of this story might be He That Hath Wings by Edmond Hamilton, but it has a young man, later an adult, as its protagonist.)

Comment: I am sorry, that seems rather close but is not the book in question. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 5):

Possibly *Wings*, by E.D. Baker?

Released in 2012, so the time frame fits.  What I can find about the story appears to be at least a partial match.

I have not read it, but it is apparently about a girl who grows wings.  I read an excerpt -- her name is "Tamisin", and she dances in a dance group in her school -- does that ring a bell?  She also has pointy ears, which she hides under her hair.

She is surprised to have wings sprout.  It turned out that her parents had adopted her from fairyland.  So, fairy and not angel.  I have not seen anything in the descriptions about her trying to hide the wings, so I am not sure whether this is a match....

Comment: I am not sure either. I think the parents were unaware of the situation. Nevertheless, thanks, i will have a look for that book as well.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like the *Maximum Ride* series by James Patterson, which I recall reading around the same time. I can't identify the exact book in this case (wherein Max first gets wings), but maybe this can be a starting point. I remember there being part of the narrative involving Max getting wings, and the entire story revolved around "Angels" with one book even being called "The Angel Experiment." The publishing timeframe fits as well.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_Ride

> *Maximum Ride* is a series of young adult science fantasy novels by the author James Patterson. The series centers on the adventures of Maximum "Max" Ride and her family, called the Flock, who are winged human-avian hybrids created at a lab called The School. The series is a reboot of Patterson's earlier novels *When the Wind Blows* and *The Lake House*, which were aimed for older audiences.

Comment: As I recall, *Maximum Ride* starts with Max and company already having full-fledged wings. If there was a scene from when the wings weren't fully grown, as the OP describes, it would have had to be a flashback.

Comment: @DLosc Good to note - I believe this is correct as I recall them starting with wings as well, so I think indeed it would have had to be a flashback.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. The family did not have wings. She had to hide the wings from the family. So, i guess this is no match. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

***[The Quest for the Worldbooks](https://www.goodreads.com/series/108488-la-qu-te-des-livres-mondes)*** series (2008-2012) by Carina Rozenfeld looks similar. Could be the one you're looking for.

Here's the Goodreads synopsis for the first book in the series, *[The Book of Souls](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6340326-le-livre-des-mes)* (2008):

> Zec let himself fall forward, as if he was going to dive. He felt his heart pounding like crazy in his chest as he fell. The black water of the canal drew closer... Without him having to think, his instinct took over and his wings began to beat, lifting the air around him, straightening it, making it rise, higher, even higher. Until his face was turned towards the stars, until he felt the air cool around him, until he completely realized that he was really flying, that it wasn't a dream this time... Zec is 16 years old and living a perfectly normal adolescence... until, after a very restless night, wings grow in his back. Zec soon learns that he is from a parallel universe that disappeared into Void because of the Swallower of Worlds, and that his mission is to resurrect it. With the help of Eden, a winged girl like him, he must find the three World-Books, hidden on Earth, in which the Souls, Places and History of this lost world are recorded. But this Quest promises to be highly dangerous because the Swallower of Worlds is determined to finish what he started...

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! Can you explain *how* this book is similar? Also note that OP claims the book was in English or German, not French. Is there an English translation of the book available?

Comment: I am 95 % sure that the protagonist was female. So, sorry but thank you.